# Unable to Instantiate and questions about OnActivityResult

Tags: android, instantiation, onactivityresult

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int GET_MOVIE = 1000;
private Button btn1;
String movie;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    movie = btn1.getText().toString();

    Log.e("kjw", "outlistener_main");
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {



            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MovieActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("movie", movie);

            startActivityForResult(i, GET_MOVIE);


        }
    });
}

public void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == GET_MOVIE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    movie = data.getExtras().getString("return");
    btn1.setText(movie);
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}
```

}

```
public class MovieActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON

private String url = "http://www.kobis.or.kr/kobisopenapi/webservice/rest/boxoffice/searchDailyBoxOfficeList.json?key=165fd244a33a11b50938eacd1fcbe6aa&targetDt=20140107";

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String curY = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
String curM = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
String curD = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) - 1);
String day = curY + curM + curD;

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_BOXOFFICERESULT = "boxOfficeResult";
private static final String TAG_DAILYBOXOFFICELIST = "dailyBoxOfficeList";
private static final String TAG_RNUM = "rnum";
private static final String TAG_MOVIENM = "movieNm";
private static final String TAG_OPENDT = "openDt";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray movies = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String> > movieList;

TextView t;
String movie;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d("Response", ">" + "a" );
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie);

    Log.d("Response", ">" + "b" );

    movieList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    Log.d("Response", ">" + "c" );

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();

    Log.d("Response", ">" + "d" );

    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movienm);
    movie = t.getText().toString();
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    Log.e("kjw", "outlistener");

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            Intent i = getIntent();
            movie = i.getStringExtra("movie");
            i.putExtra("return", movie);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();               
        }

    });


}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MovieActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        Log.d("Response", ">" + "1" );

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response", ">" + "2" );


        if (jsonStr != null) {

            Log.d("Response", ">" + "22" );


            try {
                Log.d("Response", ">" + "222" );
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                Log.d("Response", ">" + "2222" );


                JSONObject a = jsonObj.getJSONObject(TAG_BOXOFFICERESULT);
                Log.d("Response", ">" + "22222" );


                movies = a.getJSONArray(TAG_DAILYBOXOFFICELIST);

                for (int i=0; i <movies.length(); i++) {

                    Log.d("Response", ">" + "222222" );

                    JSONObject c  = movies.getJSONObject(i);
                    String rnum = c.getString(TAG_RNUM);
                    String movienm = c.getString(TAG_MOVIENM);
                    String opendt = c.getString(TAG_OPENDT);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> movie = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    movie.put(TAG_RNUM, rnum);
                    movie.put(TAG_OPENDT, opendt);
                    movie.put(TAG_MOVIENM, movienm);

                    Log.d("Response", ">" + "2222222" );
                    // adding contact to contact list
                    movieList.add(movie);
                    Log.d("Response", ">" + "2222222222" );
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + "2b");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Log.d("Response", ">" + "2000");
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MovieActivity.this, movieList, R.layout.list_item, 
                new String[] { TAG_RNUM, TAG_OPENDT, TAG_MOVIENM }, new int[] { R.id.rnum, R.id.opendt, R.id.movienm });


        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

}

```
public class ServiceHandler {

static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler() {

}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}
```

}

**My Logcat trace**

01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test_06/com.example.test_06.MovieActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4946)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at com.example.test_06.MovieActivity.onCreate(MovieActivity.java:76)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
01-09 22:13:08.625: E/AndroidRuntime(27625):    ... 11 more

I attached another error... I fall in deep thinking about 3 hours T.T

Answer (score 0):

You must find btn1 inside onCreate method and also assign value to String "movie" inside onCreate method after find button btn1.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null pointer exception-

21:15:52.795: E/AndroidRuntime(20193): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 01-09

beacuse you are not initializing btn1 inside onCreate() method. Write this line inside onCreate()-

```
btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always access the `Views` after calling the `setContentView()` method in android. Without inflating layout you can not directly access the view from declaration part.

Declare your `Button` inside `onCreate()` not at the declaration part.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int GET_MOVIE = 1000;
private Button btn1;
private String movie;
Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   movie = btn1.getText().toString();
```

Also below code should be in `onCreate()` only. And to get the Value of `TextView` you should write `String movie = t.getText().toString();` instead of `String movie=t.toString();`

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movienm);
movie = t.getText().toString();
.
.
.

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    Log.e("kjw", "outlistener");

    Intent i = getIntent();

    movie = i.getStringExtra("movie");
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            Intent i = getIntent();
            movie = i.getStringExtra("movie");
            i.putExtra("return", movie);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();               
        }

    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Then How I put movie? If I put movie in onCreate(), I cannot access OnActivityResult. How do I?

Comment: Which movie are you talking about?

Comment: private static final int GET_MOVIE = 1000;
 private Button btn1;
 String movie;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  movie = btn1.getText().toString();                     I modified like this

Comment: That should be also in onCreate(). It might be getting crashed because the value of `btn1` may be not getting. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Check out my updated answer . Also make sure your Button which you are trying to access resides inside your `activity_main` layout only.  @sunsets

Comment: Change your this line `String movie = t.toString();` to `String movie = t.getText().toString();`

Comment: I'm done just now but I found the error movie = t.getText().toString().

Comment: @sunsets Please update your code also and properly format it. Its not at all understandable what you have done.

Comment: What is `movieList` ?

Answer (score 0):

This `btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);`

```
 private Button btn1;   
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Should be in onCreate after `setContentView`

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the current inflated layout. So you need to set the content of layout to the activity first then initialize your views.

Also

```
private String movie;
private Button btn1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    movie = btn1.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I modified your suggested code but It does not work still. I attached below origin writing.

Comment: @sunsets post the full code i believe you have some statements oustide of any method

Comment: @sunsets where do you set adapter for listview? and what is line 55 `MovieActivity.java`?

Answer (score 0):

findViewById() must be called AFTER setContentView(). [The docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29):

> Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was **processed in onCreate(Bundle).**

In other words, change your button declaration to:

```
private Button btn1;
```

Then, in onCreate(), find the button AFTER setContentView():

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```